# Is it possible to install MySQL 5.5.45 on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: package-management, 22.04, mysql

I need to install MySQL 5.5.45 on Ubuntu 22.04. I was provided with legacy code using PHP 5.4.60 and MySQL 5.5.45. I didn't have any issues with installing PHP 5.4.60. But I'm not able to install MySQL 5.5.45. I've tried many ways of installing the same but none of them work, including installing via Binary files. Assuming that I need these specific versions, is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL 5.5.45 is very old and I wouldn't recommend using it, especially in production. MySQL 5.5 reached its end of life long time ago: support ended in December 2015 and extended support ended in December 2018. Please consider migrating your code to up to date version of MySQL.

However, it is possible to install MySQL 5.5.45 on Ubuntu 22.04. Here are some basic instructions:

#### Remove other MySQL versions

Make sure you have removed all previous MySQL and MariaDB installations:

```
sudo apt purge mysql-*
sudo apt purge mariadb-*
sudo apt autoremove
```

#### Download

Download MySQL 5.5.45 from https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/community/:

```
wget https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/get/p/23/file/mysql-5.5.45-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
```

#### Installation

This will install MySQL 5.5.45 in `/opt/mysql/server-5.5`:

```
sudo dpkg -i mysql-5.5.45-debian6.0-x86_64.deb
sudo apt install libncurses5
sudo groupadd mysql
sudo useradd -r -g mysql mysql
sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /opt/mysql/
sudo /opt/mysql/server-5.5/scripts/mysql_install_db --user=mysql
```

#### Usage

- Start the server:

  ```
  sudo /opt/mysql/server-5.5/support-files/mysql.server start
  ```
- Use the client:

  ```
  /opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysql
  ```

#### Change the password

To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h ubuntu2204 password 'new-password'
```

Alternatively you can run:

```
/opt/mysql/server-5.5/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

Comment: Thank You! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse.

A method is to download the `tar.gz` file of the version you want and untar it in `/opt/` (the tarball will have a unique named directory with the version number in it). A method to do this (we used that to debug beteen mysql v5 and v8):

```
/opt/mysql/mysql (<-script or service)
/opt/mysql.5.45/
/opt/mysql.5.46/
```

and then use the script/service in `/opt/mysql/` to connect to the version you need to use.

AFAIK there is nothing in mysql 5.46 that bites with 5.45 so there should be no need for this.